# What's the word describing a person who's multi-racial?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

I met a girl who has a diverse ethnic heritage. Part German, part Central American, part African-American, part some other European country that I forget.

What word can be used to describe her? Multi-ethnic, poly-ethnic? Multi-racial as in the title? What's the most proper/common term?

Answer (score 5):

*Human*. Everybody is a mix to a certain degree if you go back far enough. Despite what some like to believe, there is no such thing as a "pure breed" human.

If you really want to use a term that highlights her diversity, I would go for *mixed ethnicity* or *mixed origin* or something like that. Do not use *race* first of all because the concept itself is [not very useful](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/399/8651) and second because terms involving *race* tend to be laden with racist connotations. I am a mix of 5 different nationalities and I call myself a *European bastard* but I would not recommend that term.

It is unlikely that you will find a non-offensive single term for this since most people who feel the need to point out a person's 'racial' diversity tend to do so for discriminatory reasons. I am not saying that you are, it is just a quirk of the language's history that most such terms come from a very racist era. There used to be an [incredibly nuanced vocabulary](http://www.mixedfolks.com/names.htm) for people of various mixes of white and black for example: *mulatto, quadroon, octoroon* etc.

Anyway if you really, really want to use a term involving race, go for *mixed-race* or *[multiracial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiracial)*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very good question and one which affects my own family. My wife is entirely of Chinese descent. Hence our children are Anglo-Chinese. And our grandson's father is Anglo-Italian. We also have a foster daughter who is Anglo-Caribbean, and she has a daughter whose father is Anglo-New Guinean.

The difficulty with identifying an elegant expression which characterises mixed-race as desirable and gives it the excitement it merits, is that history has held inter-racial marriage in such dim light. And language largely follows history. Perhaps the most positive term is 'cosmopolitan', but it doesn't precisely connote mixed -race. It means a person who is at home and at ease in many different countries and cultural surroundings. There are many unfortunately negative terms.  But I think the one which we and our children would prefer would simply be 'a family/person of mixed-race'.

Of course if you go back far enough the white British themselves are potentially of mixed race. My own hair and skin-colouring suggests I follow neither the Nordic blonde, nor the Mediterranean dark appearance. And I know for sure that I have a Huguenot in my ancestry.

Comment: Interesting point, about language following history. This helps explain why there's no elegant term for it yet, as you point out. It's a shame...

Comment: You have a Huguenot in your ancestry?  Scandalous!  Seriously, a Huguenot is a French Protestant of the Calvinist school.  It's a religious persuasion, not a "race".  But I am sure you know this and are making a subtle joke about it.  Of course I fell for it.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist Merely to indicate that I was not 100% Anglo-Saxon.

Comment: Well, @WS2, who is?  I'm like you, I suppose.  British, French, German and American Indian.  A nice mixture.

Answer (score 2):

*Multiracial* is the term I personally use to describe myself, ethnically.  It's pretty universally understood, and relatively neutral.

That said, different people have very different opinions and answers to this question.  If you have a close enough relationship with the young lady in question, I suggest you ask her, tactfully, if she has a preferred ethnic descriptor.

As a side note: Tiger Woods coined the descriptor *Cablinasian* (Caucasian/Black/Indian/Asian) to describe himself (but I've never heard anyone else use that term except in jest!).